# Defending on Assault Maps

Tags: overwatch

I was just thinking about this situation I ran into yesterday;

My friends and I are defending on Hanamura. We're all fighting to defend A, and as I am chasing an enemy down to kill them, the point is captured. I kill the enemy, but we are already losing B; an enemy Genji had camped in B to get the process started quickly. As a Roadhog with no movement options, I ran the whole way back.

My question is, will it ever be quicker to jump off the map, die, and respawn? Or is running back the fastest way to do so? Is there any advantage of one way over the other, aside from the obvious flank from behind?

Comment: Chasing down an enemy is rarely a good idea when you are defending especially when the point is about to be captured. Just break off and fall back to your team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the move speed of the hero you're playing at the moment. With Roadhog your options are limited ... But in this case its not your job to rush and be the first on the point, surely you must have had more mobile units on your team who would have scaled the distance faster.

It takes 8 seconds to re spawn, 2 or 3 more seconds to run from spawn to the point and any distance you have between you and your suicide spot.

The only situation where suicide would be an OK strategy is you being on the furthest point way behind the A point where the enemy can flank. FROM there to B, the distance is greater than 10 seconds. From most other spots you can run + charge faster than 10 seconds.

Also it is worth pointing that you should really know when to run to A and when to prepare on B. I've been playing this game since release and only two days ago I got the achievement of not loosing A at all. A is pretty much always captured. If you see that there are no alive teammates and there are 3-4-5 people contesting, your HP and Damage will be far more valuable on the clutch point, instead of you running just to die immediately being jumped by 4 people.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think you're thinking of Reinherdt with that charge.  Otherwise, yes, SD'ing to catch up is usually useless as you'll lose more time.  Even if you're at the enemy's old A spawn and they're running to C, you'll be more useful in catching them off-guard at the B spawn then getting back to the front with 10~seconds of downtime.

Comment: You could also cut off the reinforcements.   Let the mobile members of your team get back to kill the Genji, you slow down the other opponents from being able to get up to help capture B.  I have a hard time justifying an SD, unless the edge is right next to you.

Comment: @Poolsharker I agree, justifying an SD is difficult. What I'm wondering also is if this is the case for Volskaya and Anubis. Also, to the edit just made, I'm normally that way, but in this case I got sidetracked by an annoying Tracer, and my teammates died in the process, allowing A to be captured. More of a wrong place at the wrong time kind of moment.